# Make use of Global.asa in IIS 8.5 without converting folder into application

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, global.asa

I was configuring an ASP classic app which was hosted in Windows 2003 server on IIS6.0 into Windows Server 2012 IIS8.5. The app has oracle DB which was configured using ODBC DSN with oracle 11g thin client driver.

The issue is when configuring the app as site is not using Global.asa & code is breaking as DB connection settings were present in Global.asa. When converting site to application by mentioning the parent path &  converting virtual directory to site Global.asa configurations are working but to connect with DB its using _ScriptLibrary/RecordSet.ASP file along with some conn.ASP file where a connection is established within javascript code block and most the images and include files are hard coded with site URL and now these have to be modified with the context path.

So is there any way for the app to use Global.asa without converting into application?

Comment: Sorry, but would you mind rewording this - I can't read the main paragraph - it simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: What procedures/practices have to be followed for migrating ASP classic applications from IIS 6.0 to IIS 8.5